# How do I increment an iterator inside a for loop body c++

Tags: list, for-loop, iterator, concatenation, increment

I'm trying to join to simple char lists together one element at a time to create a new list. For example, if listA = 1,2,3,4,5 and listB = a,b,c,d,e,f, listC = a,1,b,2,c,3 etc...

```
I have a function taking in two char list, but I'm not able to increment the iterators from list A and B without receiving a compiler error.

My code is as follows:

void altFusion(std::list<char> listOne, std::list<char> listTwo) {
    std::list<char>::iterator iter;
    std::list<char>::iterator nextIter;

    iter = listOne.begin();
    nextIter = listTwo.begin();
    std::list<char>newList;


    char temp = *iter;
    char temp2 = *nextIter;



    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newList.push_back(temp);
        newList.push_back(temp2);
        ++iter;
        ++nextIter;

    }

    std::list<char>::iterator newListIter;
    for (newListIter = newList.begin(); newListIter != newList.end(); ++newListIter) {
        std::cout << *newListIter;
    }
}
```

If I'm not allowed to increment my iterator inside the body of the for loop, how should I?

If I remove the ++iter and ++nextIter, the program works, but the answer isn't desirable. (a,1,a,1,a,1,a,1...)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
std::list<char> listA = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
std::list<char> listB = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
        //listC = a,1,b,2,c,3 etc...
int main()
{

    std::list<char> new_list;

    for (auto iterator = listA.begin(), end = listA.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
    {
        // get current index
        int index = std::distance(listA.begin(), iterator);
        // insert item from list a
        new_list.push_back(*iterator);

        // listb item
        auto it = listB.begin();
        std::advance(it, index);

        new_list.push_back( *it);

    }

    for (auto n : new_list)
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the reason why your post increment and pre increment is not working because of this. your just using the same value over and over again. your are not replacing temp and temp2.

```
newList.push_back(temp);
newList.push_back(temp2);
```

Comment: I see you increment through your list using std::advance() is there a reason you're using this and why using pre and post (++) doesn't work? Is it an issue of scope?
I haven't tried your solution as of yet.

Comment: std::advance just increments the iterator by n elements. if it is negative it is decremented.

Comment: your code is now working because of this.newList.push_back(temp);
 newList.push_back(temp2);

Comment: move these two lines inside the for loop before you push_back. char temp = *iter;    char temp2 = *nextIter; i don't know how to remove a comment. the comment above should say your code is not working because of this.